# C++: Array of external class functions

Tags: c++

I am using a library that wants an array of functions, like this:

**Original main.cpp:**

```c
void test1(OLEDDisplay* display, OLEDDisplayUiState* state, int16_t x, int16_t y) {}

void test2(OLEDDisplay* display, OLEDDisplayUiState* state, int16_t x, int16_t y) {}

void OledDisplay() {
  FrameCallback f[] = {test1, test2};
  ui.setFrames(f, 2);
}
```

...and that works well. But I want to place test1 and test2 in a class in another linked file:

****ilb.h:****

```c
class ILB {
 public:
  ILB();
  void test1(OLEDDisplay*, OLEDDisplayUiState* , int16_t, int16_t);
  void test2(OLEDDisplay*, OLEDDisplayUiState* , int16_t, int16_t);
};
```

**ilb.cpp:**

```c
...
void ILB::test1(OLEDDisplay *display, OLEDDisplayUiState* state, int16_t x, int16_t y) {}
void ILB::test2(OLEDDisplay *display, OLEDDisplayUiState* state, int16_t x, int16_t y) {}
...
```

**New main.cpp:**

```c
ILB ilb;

void OledDisplay() {
  FrameCallback f[] = {ilb.test1, ilb.test2};
  ui.setFrames(f, 2);
}
```

And that gives me this error:

```
src/main.cpp:35:44: error: cannot convert 'ILB::test1' from type 'void (ILB::)(OLEDDisplay*, OLEDDisplayUiState*, int16_t, int16_t)' {aka 'void (ILB::)(OLEDDisplay*, OLEDDisplayUiState*, short int, short int)'} to type 'FrameCallback' {aka 'void (*)(OLEDDisplay*, OLEDDisplayUiState*, short int, short int)'}
```

I can't figure out what is missing...

Comment: `ILB::test1` and `ILB::test2` are member functions. they are different than free functions since they need n instance of an `ILB` object

Comment: Look at the error message carefully.  `void(ILB::)(...)` can not be converted to `void(*)(...)`.  The former is a member function that requires the presense of an `ILB`.  The later is not a member function.

Comment: Also, the code presented here is not _really_ the code giving you an error on **line 35** of main.cpp.  This is not a [mre] and this code would produce [different errors](https://godbolt.org/z/hsE7fh4xM).

Comment: Use `std::function` and an explicit closure. You have to close around a sufficiently long-lived `this` value.

Comment: See https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/pointers-to-members

Comment: Based on the error message what you call "an array of functions" is more accurately described as "an array of function pointers". To save readers from having to make that inference, please add the definition of `FrameCallback` to your question. *(This is relevant since an array of `std::function` objects could also be called "an arrray of functions".)*